# MySQL Get users who have received comment within 24 hours and not responded

Tags: mysql

I have a web app where users can send comments to each other.

I need to find users who have received a comment and have not sent a comment to any user within 24 hours.

The relevant tables/fields are: user.id, comment.recipient, comment.sender, comment.date

Here is what I have so far:

```
SELECT u.* FROM user AS u 
INNER JOIN comment AS c1 ON u.id = c1.recipient
INNER JOIN comment AS c2 ON u.id = c2.sender
WHERE c2.date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY )
AND c2.recipient = c1.sender
AND c1.date < c2.date
GROUP BY u.id
```

**UPDATE**

Here is what worked for me, thanks to Frazz:

```
SELECT u.id,u.firstName,u.lastName
FROM user AS u 
JOIN comment AS c1 ON u.id = c1.recipient
WHERE DATE(c1.date) BETWEEN ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 47 HOUR ) AND ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 24 HOUR )
AND NOT EXISTS (
SELECT c2.sender
FROM comment AS c2
WHERE c2.date > c1.date
AND c2.sender = u.id
)
GROUP BY u.id
```

Comment: If you are looking for users that did NOT respond to comments, I don't see why you are INNER JOINing c2. I would rather expect a NOT EXISTS or a LEFT JOIN with an IS NULL test on c2.sender ;)

Comment: Yeah I'm a little lost, I changed the second join to a LEFT JOIN. Trying to do this without multiple queries/subqueries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a first quick look I'd say you are looking for something like this:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM user    AS u 
JOIN comment AS c1 ON u.id = c1.recipient
WHERE c1.date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY )
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT sender
  FROM comment AS c2
  WHERE c2.date > c1.date
  AND   c2.sender = u.id
  AND   c2.recipient = c1.sender)
```

You can also obtain the same result with a LEFT JOIN, testing for NULL in the c2.sender column, like so:

```
SELECT u.*
FROM      user    AS u 
JOIN      comment AS c1 ON u.id = c1.recipient
LEFT JOIN comment AS c2 ON u.id = c2.sender AND c1.sender = c2.recipient
WHERE c1.date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY )
AND   c2.date > c1.date
AND   c2.sender IS NULL
```

I'd prefer the first. LEFT JOINs can be costly and should be used only if actually needed. This is not the case here, as you're essentially looking for rows that do not match.

I took out the GROUP BY, as I'm not really sure what you were trying to obtain from it. GROUPing a query where you have a SELECT * is risky... you can never be quite sure of which row the engine will keep and which will be discarded. If you want just one row per user, then you better state the logic to use to choose one in case a same user has not responded to multiple comments from different other users.

From the comments you've added, if you only need the user id, then you can simplify the first query like so:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c1.recipient
FROM comment AS c1
WHERE c1.date >= ( CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY )
AND NOT EXISTS (
  SELECT sender
  FROM comment AS c2
  WHERE c2.date > c1.date
  AND   c2.sender = c1.recipient
  AND   c2.recipient = c1.sender)
```

In this case the DISTINCT will take care of users that have to respond to more than one comment they received.

Comment: Essentially I just want the unique user.id because I will be sending them an email prompting them for activity. I had the star in there for now because I was testing it locally in phpmyadmin and wanted to see some of the other user data

Comment: The first solution is close, but still not quite right. I created 2 new comments from different users and they both showed up. Then I logged in as one of these users and left a comment for a 3rd user. Now all 3 users show up in result set

Comment: That seems correct. Or at least, that's what I understood you were asking for. You want to exclude users that have responded to all comments received in the last 24 hours, is that not so?

Comment: That is correct. Unfortunately, that is not what is happenning. It appears that if a user has received a comment within 24 hours and has sent a comment within 24 hours they are still selected

Comment: I like the updated query, thank you. However, I'm still getting users in the result set that have sent comments recently. I should also mention that they don't have to reply to every user. Just have sent a comment within 24 hours of their most recent receivedcomment. We are basically just checking for activity. I suppose we would need to check that the most recent comment received is no more than 47 hours old, so that we don't repeat

Comment: I finally got it. Thanks for your help. I had to take off the last AND from the where clause because we only cared about activity and not responding to a specific comment. I also need to use DATE() for c1.date. I'll update my question